# httpErrors conditional on errorMode?

Tags: asp.net

How can I make existingResponse conditional on the errorMode?

For example, If errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" then I want external messages to be "replaced" by my custom definitions i.e. a Friendly error page, but I want local messages to be "passedThrough". So, for a 500 error I see the YSOD locally, not the IIS 500 error page. Externally I would see my Friendly error page.

Is this possible?

my current configuration:

```
<httpErrors existingResponse="Replace" errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly">
    <remove statusCode="500" />
    <error statusCode="500" path="/myCustomErrorPage" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it's not possible to do this. You can use the event log to see the detail, and you could also email yourself with the error details:

```
<healthMonitoring enabled="true" heartbeatInterval="0">
    <eventMappings>
        <clear />
        <add name="All Errors" type="System.Web.Management.WebBaseErrorEvent, System.Web,Version=2.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" startEventCode="0" endEventCode="2147483647" />
    </eventMappings>
    <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="EmailProvider" type="System.Web.Management.SimpleMailWebEventProvider" to="youemail@example.com" from="webserver@example.com" buffer="true" bufferMode="Logging" />
        <add name="EventLogProvider" type="System.Web.Management.EventLogWebEventProvider" />
    </providers>
    <rules>
        <clear />
        <add name="EmailRule" eventName="All Errors" provider="EmailProvider" profile="Default" minInstances="1" maxLimit="Infinite" minInterval="00:01:00" />
        <add name="EventLogRule" eventName="All Errors" provider="EventLogProvider" profile="Default" minInstances="1" maxLimit="Infinite" minInterval="00:01:00" />
    </rules>
</healthMonitoring>
```

Adjust the minInterval if you only want to receive the notifications for example every hour or every day.  And of course, make sure you have configured your email for your webserver. E.g.

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory">
            <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="C:\MailPickUpFolders\ExampleDomain" />
            <network host="localhost" port="25" />
        </smtp>
        <!--<smtp deliveryMethod="Network">
            <network host="yoursever" port="25" />
        </smtp>-->
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```